# multiple arguments for views2 to build a path

Tags: drupal-6, view, arguments, taxonomy, pathauto

I have the usual suspects in place. Have taxonomy such as:

```
+Guys
--Core Collection
--New Arrivals
-- etc, etc
+Girls
--Core Collection
--New Arrivals
-- etc, etc
+Sale Items
```

You get the idea here. 
Anyway, i have taxonomy menu building paths (with path alias) like "/collection/guys/core-collection/some-clothing-name". I want to build a custom view so that the path displays the view with taxonomy terms as they arguments to filter on. Anyone have any information on how to pass 2 arguments from the url to filter out the items of clothing? trying now to have to build my own module but it seems i may have to go down that road.

ideally, i'd like to have "collection/%/%". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert the **`term names`** to **`term IDs`**. I'm not going to take credit for the solution but there is a post where it describe how you can solve the transformation from **`term name`** to **`term ID`**.

Rafael already suggested how to approach the path alias, so I think that chapter is covered.

Source: http://groups.drupal.org/node/8500

Comment: it would appear after reading this group that this is exactly what i'm looking for. i'll most likely be checking this out this weekend. although you may not take the credit for development, you surely will take credit in pointing me to the promise land! thanks

Comment: Glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand. You want a view to show, for example, all items on the guys/core-collection category, right? See if this works:

1. Enable the "taxonomy" view that comes by default with the views module (the one that takes taxonomy/term/% as arguments)
2. Configure the path alias for every taxonomy term of that vocabulary using the "pathauto" module to be "collection/[catpath-raw]", this way you'll get the whole term hierarchy rendered into the alias
3. That's it, you'll just need to link to "taxonomy/term/(tid)" and the alias will be automatically displayed on the URL. This will also work on every link for a term of that vocabulary on the site.

Comment: yes but the issue with this is the fact that taxonomy/term/% only is taking into account one argument and not two. so for instance, if i pass it 'guys/new-arrivals', only guys will show up and not sorted on the node that has both taxonomy terms 'guys' AND 'new-arrivals'. the sql query even shows this. i can't seem to get it to take in a 2nd argument. 

however, i think i may have a few ideas and some better success with  term-id.

Comment: The only change you need to do is alter the "depth" argument in the taxonomy view... if you specify a depth of 2, the view will display results for guys AND new-arrivals

Comment: i tried that a few times but couldn't get it working correctly. i'll also look at this one this weekend.